# Code works great but I don't know how to do reverse process in the second step

Tags: c, arrays

I've just build a code which splits 5 numbers and places it at the end of the other side.

```
ex. (left side)

1 2 3 4 5

n=2

3 4 5 1 2
```

This works great but I'm trying to do reverse, let the numbers taken from right side and putted into the left side. Here is my full code. (Left and Right is exact same, I know.) I need some help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
    int number[100]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int i,n=5,a,j;
    int num;

    printf("Enter 1(Left) or 2(Right)\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num==1)
    {
        printf ("Enter the position of the element to split the array from left.\n");
        scanf ("%d",&a);

        for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
        {
            number[n] = number[0];

            for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
            {
                number[j] = number[j+1];
            }
        }

        printf("The resultant array is\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            printf ("%d ",number[i]);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Enter the position of the element to split the array from right.\n");
        scanf ("%d",&a);

        for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
        {
            number[n] = number[0];

            for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
            {
                number[j] = number[j+1];
            }
        }

        printf("The resultant array is\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            printf ("%d ",number[i]);
        }
    }
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @iharob my code is true. I'm trying to do the reverse for the 2nd situation "2(Right)". How to make it work as the reverse of 1st situation?

Comment: Properly coded, a right-shift is identical to a left shift, but the number of elements is `len-n` rather than `n`. And you can do this in-place, btw, using three sequence reversals. [see it live](http://ideone.com/iw43Rj)

Comment: The 'print resultant array' code is a fairly big repeat; you could place it outside the `if`/`else` block since the code is identical.  It's generally a good idea to end lines of output with a newline.

Comment: strongly suggest building the new array in a second variable.  Then overlap and similar problems would be eliminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
    {
        for (j=n-1; j>=0; --j)
        {
            number[j+1] = number[j];
        }
        number[0] = number[n];
    }
```

Here you are moving each character to the right of the array by 1 element, and then you assing the last element to the first, repeat `a` times.